# WordPress Meta Box Plugin - Field Groups - Price Currency

Tags: wordpress, plugins, meta-boxes

I'm trying to build a card template for tours with Meta Box plugin.
I got everything right except the number field in the field groups. On the frontend, I would like to show a currency symbol after the number.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you!

I checked the documentation, videos etc. but there was nothing about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no code. It's a WordPress plugin.
https://metabox.io/